# Am I creating the Protocol correctly?

Tags: c, protocols, network-protocols

I am trying to make a protocol (built ontop of TCP) that can send strings from the client to the server on port 457. Here is what I have so far:

Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
             sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR on binding");
    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                       (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                       &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR on accept");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    n = write(newsockfd,"U got your messaze",18);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0; 
}
```

Client.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
          (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
          server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

I feel as though I am not setting up the protocol properly. Am I?

Comment: what do you means by *correctly*? does it works correctly?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I want to make sure that I'm not making an http server or anything else than what I am intending to make. I am afraid of this because I am making the protocol without any guidelines or help whatsoever

Comment: no, its not http/ftp serve, even you shouldn't call it protocol, its a simple tcp-application-developed in C

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan What do I need to do to make it into a protocol?

Comment: it need long answer :( --that can be used by other-application in/with well defined steps.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Sorry, I didn't understand your comment...

Comment: One tip: `bzero` is [deprecated](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html), use `memset` instead

Answer (score 0):

You should write a specification for your protocol first. Then, after reviewing it, you implement the specification. You are basically asking us to reverse engineer your protocol. This is a backwards approach to creating a protocol. You should already have a clear intent of what your program needs to do before you begin implementing it.

Your server program acts as a limited kind of ECHO server, in that no more than 255 bytes of input from the client is accepted. Whatever the server was able to read is logged to the console, and the message `U got your messaze` is sent to the client as a response.

Some issues you may want to address:

- Although unlikely, it is possible that your `read()` call returns with less data than what the client sent, even if the client sends less than 256 bytes. For example, if the client sends `aaaaaaaaaa` one byte at a time, your server might only see the first `a`, and assume it is a complete message.
- You don't take precautions against writing to an already closed connection. This may generate `SIGPIPE`, and cause your program to exit unexpectedly.
- Signals generally may interrupt your system calls. You should detect this condition and restart your system calls if that occurs.

Comment: Ok. I will write a specification. Thanks

Comment: well I did it. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qp9Z1SPBECeqeZc_E3n2RfAux9ScZo8OQSYgnRkorL4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user2420649: That's a start, but not quite enough information for someone else to implement it. Consider your description versus [a very early version of HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html). Also, compare with the description of [STOMP](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have some incorrect types:

---

`htons` expects `uint16_t` as parameter

```
htons((uint16_t)portno);
```

---

`read()` and `write()` expects `ssize_t`

```
ssize_t n;
```

---

`bzero` is deprecated, use

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
```

---

`bcopy` is deprecated, use

```
memmove(server->h_addr, &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
```

---

NUL terminate `buffer` when `read()` is used

```
/* bzero(buffer,256); Not needed */
n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
buffer[n]= '\0'; /* here */
printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
```

And note that modern programs uses `send()` and `recv()` instead of `read()` and `write()`

---

Finally, don't use magic numbers

```
fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
```

instead:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin); /* 256 */
```

And why 255? the fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, so 256 is correct.